# PsExec returning only the first line of stdout inside of a BackgroundJob

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am having an issue with the stdout of PsExec being different inside of a BackgroundJob.

Some information about the environment I am working in:

I have a large amount of Windows XP machines that do not have WinRM and I am unable to use WMI calls, however PsExec works. I need to get the stdout of a command from all of the XP machines. I was able to get the stdout I expected outside of a BackgroundJob, however when I attempt to PsExec inside of a BackgroundJob I only receive the first line of the stdout.

Here is an example of the difference I am seeing:

```
# 1.2.3.4 = IP Address of an XP Machines
# 123.123.123.123 = IP of a server I want to compare the time against.

$output = & "path\to\psexec\psexec.exe" "\\1.2.3.4" -accepteula -u "$($creds.Username)" -p "$($creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)" w32tm /stripchart /computer:123.123.123.123 /samples:1 /dataonly

Write-Host $output
```

This code outputs: `Tracking 123.123.123.123 [123.123.123.123]. Collecting 1 samples. The current time is 6/30/2021 2:41:51 PM (local time). 14:41:51, +00.0059682s`

However, this code outputs something different:

```
Start-Job -Name "1.2.3.4" -ScriptBlock {
    # 1.2.3.4 = IP Address of an XP Machines
    # 123.123.123.123 = IP of a server I want to compare the time against.

    $output = & "path\to\psexec\psexec.exe" "\\1.2.3.4" -accepteula -u "$($using:creds.Username)" -p "$($using:creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)" w32tm /stripchart /computer:123.123.123.123 /samples:1 /dataonly
    
    return $output
}

$returnValue = Get-Job "1.2.3.4" | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

Write-Host $returnValue
```

This outputs: `Tracking 123.123.123.123 [123.123.123.123].` Which is the first line of the stdout of `w32tm /stripchart /computer:123.123.123.123 /samples:1 /dataonly`.

Am I doing this incorrectly? My understanding is that there should not be a difference in the stdout inside and outside of a BackgroundJob.

I am rather new to PowerShell. If my understanding is incorrect, please enlighten me. Any information or advice you can give me would be helpful.

Thank you!

Update: After reading through Iconiu's Answer on this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666789/capturing-output-of-psexec-using-powershell-changes-the-output)

It appears that this is a limitation of PowerShell. I am currently working on a workaround for this. I will update the question again when I have a working one.

Update2: I have found a workaround that works for my purpose and I figured I would share it.

```
$ip = '1.2.3.4' # IP of an XP Machine
$otherip = '123.123.123.123' # Machine I want use for w32tm

# Create the temp Folder outside of the job if it does not exist.
if(!(Test-Path "\\$ip\c`$\temp\")) {
    MKDIR "\\$ip\c`$\temp\"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 # Sleep for one second to allow for network lag.
}

Start-Job -Name $ip -ScriptBlock {
    $ip = $using:ip
    $otherip = $using:otherip
    $creds = $using:creds 
    & "path\to\psexec\psexec.exe" \\$ip -accepteula -u $creds.Username -p $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password cmd /c "w32tm /stripchart /computer:$otherip /samples:1 /dataonly > C:\temp\w32tmstripchart.txt"
    if(Test-Path "\\$ip\c`$\temp\w32tmstripchart.txt") {
        $stdout = Get-Content -Path "\\$ip\c`$\temp\w32tmstripchart.txt" -Raw
        return $stdout
    } else {
        return "ERROR"
    
}

$retVal = Get-Job -Name $ip | Receieve-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

Write-Host $retVal
```

If you would like to capture stderr as well as stdout from the command add `2>&1` after directing the output to a file. For example, `w32tm /stripchart /computer:123.123.123.123 /samples:1 /dataonly > w32tmstripchart.txt 2>&1`

If you would prefer the stdout to be an array of strings instead of a single string, remove the `-Raw` switch from the `Get-Content` command.

Hope this is helpful to anyone in the future facing a similar problem.

Comment: A few asides: For conceptual clarity, it's better to use `&` rather than `.` when invoking external programs. To wait synchronously for the job to finish and to collect all its output and then delete it, a single statement will do: `$returnValue = Get-Job "1.2.3.4" | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob`

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but there may be a way to bypass your problem: Is using PowerShell's remoting an option, or is `psexec` the only option?

Comment: I believe that I cannot use Powershell's remoting because it uses WinRM on the remote host.

Comment: I edited the question to use the code from your first comment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Indeed there seems to be a problem with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) reporting *only* the *first* stdout line from `psexec`'s output**.

- I encourage you to report this problem, which still exists as of PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.7, at the [PowerShell (Core) GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Needs-Triage&template=Bug_Report.yaml).

`Start-Job` creates *child-process*-based background jobs, but **there is a lighter-weight, generally preferable *thread*-based alternative, [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob), which does *not* have the same problem.**

- `Start-ThreadJob` *comes with* PowerShell (Core) v6+, and can be installed *on demand* in *Windows PowerShell* v3+ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57695382/45375).

Therefore, try the following, which uses `Start-ThreadJob`:

```sh
Start-ThreadJob -Name 1.2.3.4 -ScriptBlock {
  & 'path\to\psexec\psexec.exe' -nobanner \\1.2.3.4 -accepteula -u $using:creds.Username -p ($using:creds).GetNetworkCredential().Password w32tm /stripchart /computer:123.123.123.123 /samples:1 /dataonly 2>$null
}
```

If you also want to capture `w32tm`'s *stderr* output:

```
Start-ThreadJob -Name 1.2.3.4 -ScriptBlock {
  & 'path\to\psexec\psexec.exe' -nobanner \\1.2.3.4 -accepteula -u $using:creds.Username -p ($using:creds).GetNetworkCredential().Password cmd /c 'w32tm /stripchart /computer:123.123.123.123 /samples:1 /dataonly 2>&1' 2>$null
}
```

Comment: This would work if I was able to use Install-Module, but sadly people above me have removed PowerShellGet. I am looking into if it is possible for me to install Start-ThreadJob on my workstation, use Save-Module and import it to the script host. I wound up using a batch file that saved the stdout and stderr of w32tm locally on the remote machine and then read from that file, which is a little messy but it got the job done. I am marking your answer as correct as it works on my workstation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Bummer that you don't have access to `PowerShellGet`, but I'm glad you found a workaround.